# Titles inside a flex div with same height

Tags: css, flexbox

I am setting up html cards. They all need to be the same height, but not only that, I need the titles inside the cards to be the same height as well so the description always starts at the same point, regardless of title length. Here is a codepen link with the issue:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KLjXyx

```css
{
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      margin: 0 auto; 
      max-width: 60em;
      line-height: 1.3;
    }
    ul, li {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    h2 {
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0.4em;
    }

    /*Flex items*/
    .list {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .list-item {
     display: flex; 
      padding: 0.5em;
     width: 100%;
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 40em) {
      .list-item {
        width: 50%;
      }
    }
    @media all and (min-width: 60em) {
      .list-item {
        width: 33.33%;
      }
    }
    .list-content {
     background-color: #fff;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 1em;
     width: 100%;
    }
    .list-content p {
     flex: 1 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-content">
          <h2>This title is way longer than the rest, yet I need the rest to be the same height so the paragraph starts at the same point</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eveniet.</p>
          <a href="">Link</a>
        </div>
      </li>

         <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-content">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
          <a href="">Link</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="list-item">
        <div class="list-content">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
          <a href="">Link</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: So the other two paragraphs would start at the bottom of the card even though the title is one line? :/ Even if you _can_, I'm not sure you _should_ do what you're asking. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @stealththeninja The amount of text in my example is just an exaggeration to prove the point, but normally the title would be one or two lines taller, and I would like the description to start at the same point in every card.

Comment: There is **no CSS method** to align elements that **do not share a parent.**

Answer (score 1):

```js
var maxheight=0;
$("h2").each(function(){
 if($(this).height()>maxheight){
  maxheight=$(this).height();
 }
})
$("h2").height(maxheight);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto; 
  max-width: 60em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
}

/*Flex items*/
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.list-item {
 display: flex; 
  padding: 0.5em;
 width: 100%;
}
@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  .list-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 60em) {
  .list-item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}
.list-content {
 background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
 width: 100%;
}
.list-content p {
 flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>This title is way longer than the rest, yet I need the rest to be the same height so the paragraph starts at the same point</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eveniet.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  
  <li class="list-item">
    <div class="list-content">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
      <a href="">Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

this will always take the max-height of h2 and apply it to all other h2 elements! so all text descriptions will start at the same level!

Comment: thanks, I thought about this too, but was hoping there was a way that didn't involve JS.

Comment: I suggest testing a case with lots of cards and max title outside the page view (would the browser calculate the longest title height as 0 and miscalculate the max height?)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the third parameter of `flex` to control this, with, for example, `flex: 0 0 60%` on the `h2` element.

Note that you may want to adjust the height of your elements to accommodate this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 60em;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.4em;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}


/*Flex items*/

.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5em;
  width: 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 40em) {
  .list-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 60em) {
  .list-item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  h2 {
    
  }
}

.list-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.list-content p {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<li class="list-item">
  <div class="list-content">
    <h2>This title is way longer than the rest, yet I need the rest to be the same height so the paragraph starts at the same point</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio, eveniet.</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="list-item">
  <div class="list-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium, odio vel blanditiis id ea dolorum expedita fugit incidunt commodi.</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </div>
</li>

<li class="list-item">
  <div class="list-content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore, vel, quia. Non nostrum, consectetur ipsum doloribus enim maiores a laudantium.</p>
    <a href="">Link</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

Title should always be short.Update your design, ask your content writer to update that.
If alignment is only concern you may try following but title wont be displayed completely.

```
h2{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```